# Why does \verb take its argument between pipes || rather than braces {}?

Tags: verbatim, braces

Is there something fundamentally different about `\verb` compared to other commands or is it just a design choice?

Comment: What if you want a verbatim `{` :-) The use of pipes is not required by `\verb`, it's just the most common choice.

Comment: @JosephWright In that case, where did this convention come from?

Comment: @user2229219: How often do you use `|` in a document? Oh, not very often, so let's use `|` for `\verb` then, because I really don't use it often...

Comment: The `\detokenize` macro is `verbatim-like` but does take its argument between braces.  However, as Ethan's answer points out, that places limitations on its generality: 1) braces must be matched, 2) `%` is still treated as a comment (not verbatim), 3) `#` is not allowed.

Comment: The text between the pipes (or the character of your election) is not, strictly, an argument of `\verb`. This macro opens what we could call a "verbatim mode", and the first character sets how to close it.

Comment: I should add that `\detokenize` has one advantage relative to true `verbatim`... it handles line auto-breaking and margin justification.

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that the same character used to mark the start must be used to end it. So if you had `\verb{foo}`, the `}` would not end your `verb`, you would have to have `\verb{foo{`, which would be very bad for code readability. I think you could do this if you wanted though

Comment: almost _everything_ about `\verb` is fundamentally different to other commands.

Comment: You can use as  delimiters of `\verb` *any* character including numbers, spaces, and even not printable UTF8 characters.   Obviously, the exceptions are alphabet characters as "a", simply because `\verba` is another command. I left as exercise why `aaa \verb​xxx​ bbb`  works (copy &  paste the chunk code, do not simply write what you see).`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a design choice, because \verb can't know in advance what characters you might want produced verbatim. So you get to choose the delimiter on the fly each time - for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|using a pipe in \verb to get a verbatim $|

You can even use a \$ to begin and end your verbatim string:

\verb$Here's a verbatim pipe in braces: {|}$

\end{document}
```